# How do I export to a cvs file using php

Tags: php, csv

I'm having a problem getting my export to create and download a cvs file. Using the code below, this exports the data, but it prints out in the browser, rather than creating an actual csv file. I call the php from a link on another page with `<a href="export.php" target="_blank">Export Details</a>` but all it does is show the data in the browser rather than creating a csv file.

This is my code in the file export.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$data = array(
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"'
);

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
$val = explode(",", $line);
fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Can anyone see where it's going wrong?

Comment: `application/csv` should be `text/csv`

Comment: But $data is a simple array, so `$val = explode(",", $line);` on any of those elements will only ever return one $val, not an array, so you'll only ever have one entry per line

Comment: Hi Mark, changing to text/csv did not solve the issue. And yes I'm aware of the simple array, just using that for testing. The issue is, it still prints out the data in the browser and does not create/download a file named sample.csv

Comment: Have you used browser debug tools to check what response headers it's receiving?

Comment: Content type is showing as text/html in response headers

Comment: Are you calling/including this as part of a larger application that might be overriding the headers you set here?

Comment: It's in wordpress, but the code above is the only code in that file, not get_header or anything else.

Comment: Try doing a `die();` after closing the output.... that will terminate wordpress, so you'll be able to see if it's wordpress changing the headers after you've set them

Comment: With die(); in there it is showing No Response Headers

Answer (score 1):

So, after a whole afternoon of fun with this one, I finally got to the bottom of the problem. The issue wasn't with the code, it was the database I am running locally. I'm using Mamp to set up my wordpress db locally and that's where the problem was. The solution is with Output Buffering and the solution can be found here http://hibbard.eu/php-headerlocation-not-working-in-mamp/. Thanks guys for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

CSV Files are files having comma separated values on each line, maybe enclosed by a string enclosure.

First thing that catches my eye is that you pass single values to [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). But [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) wants an array of values (fields) as the second argument. So your explode is redundant - have a look at the manual page,

As you are only outputting to STDOUT (the Browser) you can simply echo your lines:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"'); 

$data = array(
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"'
);

foreach($data AS $line){
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
}   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but if you look at the discussion above with Mark, the issue is not the data that is outputted, it is the fact that it outputs it to the browser and doesn't create a cvs file. However, I tried your suggestions and I just get an empty browser window ;-)

Comment: Did you put your $data-Array in it?

Comment: Correction, your edited version works, but again it prints it out in the browser window and does not create a cvs file.

Comment: Try to put the code in http://phpfiddle.org/ and run it. Works for me. Maybe you overwrite the Response-Header somewhere else after the actual output of the csv data? Try die(); after the output foreach.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah it works in phpfiddle for me too. Must be an issue with Response-Header. It's in a wordpress theme folder, is there a way to force reading these headers instead? Adding die(); after the output shows No Response Headers in the debugger

Comment: When you output a header via the php function it overwrites the header with the same name which was outputed before. Could be an issue with the WordPress theming - but I'm not familiar with WordPress enough.

Comment: I've moved the file out of the wordpress theme. It now show No Header Response in the inspector. But still not creating the csv file.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean.

Comment: ok, sorry I get what you mean. Output is as follows:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 02 Nov 2015 15:53:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.23 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.23
Content-Type: text/html
X-Pad: avoid browser bug

Comment: The website is hosted on localhost on my machine, don't know if that is the issue??

Comment: I've just wanted to check if your browser is the problem, which is not. Right now I don't have an idea why you get text/html as content type. What happens if you make a standalone file - completely without wordpress on your localhost - and paste the example code line above? I try to figure out if your localhost installation messes something up or if it is wordpress which overwrites the response header.

Comment: Ok, so I uploaded the file to a copy of the wordpress site which I have online and it works fine! So it seems it only doesn't work on my localhost - Now I am completely confused!

Comment: Maybe it's something in the configuration of your development environment. Check the apache config files or the depending `.htaccess` file for something appropriate like [mod_header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html). Just a random shot.

Comment: I'm on the same wavelength, just checking php.ini file but not found anything yet

Comment: This is everything in the .htacces file:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Can't see anything there that would cause a problem, but I agree with you. The problem must be with my localhost db setup.

Comment: What development environment do you use? Maybe switch to a dedicated Linux-VM? Maybe via [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll have to try something else. At least I know the problem is not with my code. It should all work fine once I commit my files to the online version!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Not many people stick with a problem for so long ;-)

Comment: Ok, so I didn't want to leave this alone and eventually got to the bottom of the problem! I'll post an answer to show How I fixed it.